# CSS menu alignent issue

Tags: css, nav

I have created a CSS Navigation Bar and its divided into three parts:
1.Left (***.logo*** is class and it  placed at the Left)
2.Center (***.menu*** is another class and it placed at the Center)
3.Right  (***.menu2*** is last class and **i can't place at the Right correctly**)

**I want Something Like this and how can I achieve this task:**
[image]

```css
.logo {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
nav{
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
}
/*Menu 1*/
nav .menu ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 margin:0;
 transition: 2s;
}
nav .menu ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 16px 8px;
}
nav .menu ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
}
/*Menu 2*/
nav .menu2 ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: right;
 margin:0;
 transition: 2s;
}
nav .menu2 ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 16px 8px;
}
nav .menu2 ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <div class="logo">
  LOGO
 </div>
 <div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="menu2">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav><!----- nav ------>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might put the `menu2`s before the `Menu1`s in the HTML, and give `.menu2` `right: 0;` and `position: absolute;`:

```css
nav{
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
}
.logo {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
/*Menu 1*/
nav .menu ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 margin:0;
 transition: 2s;
}
nav .menu ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 16px 8px;
}
nav .menu ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
}
/*Menu 2*/
nav .menu2 {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
nav .menu2 ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: right;
 margin:0;
 transition: 2s;
}
nav .menu2 ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 16px 8px;
}
nav .menu2 ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <div class="logo">
  LOGO
 </div>
 <div class="menu2">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav><!----- nav ------>
```

Comment: It works, maybe '.Menu1'  is not placed at the center correctly?

Comment: Oops, you can use `right: 0` and `position: absolute` instead